# Vim binding next search ('n') to another key

Tags: vim, key-bindings

### Hi

lately, I was playing around with key bindings.
I know that for example:
`nnoremap g <Del>`
Will map delete to key 'g'. But I cannot find a way to change binding for 'n' key.
:help index  says : "repeat the latest '/' or '?' N times." How am I supposed to bind that?
Thans in advance for any answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the arguments the wrong way around:

```
:nnoremap g <Del>
```

maps the <kbd>g</kbd> key to the `<Del>` command. (Also, there must be no spaces in the `<...>` notation; see `:help key-notation`.

To add another binding (e.g. `<F5>`) for the `n` command, use:

```
:nnoremap <F5> n
```

Comment: Ok, the original idea behind the whole binding around was to perform next search on 'x'. The question is: in insert mode if I'd press x will I type in 'n' then ?

Comment: Then use `x` instead of `<F5>` in my example. And no, it will still insert `x` in insert-mode; the leading `n` in `nnoremap` restricts the mapping to _normal mode_; read `:help map-modes`.

Comment: Thank you Very much, that may be a stupid question, but hell, i couldn't find the answer. Ill look at :help more often .

Comment: Yes, the help is very good (though also dauntingly large). There are no stupid questions; the modes can be confusing, especially at first!